# What to pass to as Content to an HttpResponseMessage in unit test when the StatusCode is error 500?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am developing an asp.net core 6 web api.

I am trying to unit test a service which sends and receives responses through httpclient.
I am doing this through mocking HttpMessageHandler and constructing an HttpResponseMessage.

When the result is 200 OK - it is clear - I pass the json of the data to the Content. But what about when the response code is 500?

I can't figure out what the content is when the external service returns an error reponse?

```
            var handlerMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Content = new StringContent(@"[{ ""id"": 1, ""title"": ""Cool post!""}, { ""id"": 100, ""title"": ""Some title""}]"),
            };
```

Comment: The code you included doesn't seem to be about any kind of test for a 500 responses.  Have you debugged the test and see what is in the content of the HTTP Response? It very well may contain nothing.

Comment: You test against an expected behavior. Expected means documented. If the response here is not defined/documented you can't test it. My opinion would be to ignore the content in the 500 case then.

Comment: If you have an established failure message you can interpret then you would want to create a unit test to model that. Otherwise, I would treat the endpoint as any endpoint that might potentially fail and unit test how my service would do in case it failed. That can be simulated by setting the status code to an unsuccessful status code exclude any content to see how your app would handle it. This would be a new unit test so it doesn't affect your Successful handle unit test.